# Angular - making an input field required

Tags: angularjs

I don't know Angular but now I have to make an input form in an Angular app required.
Is this the right way to do it?

I just added **required="{{'required'}}"** to it:

```
<input type="text" required="{{'required'}}" ng-model='config.test' placeholder="{some text}}">
```

Comment: Assuming AngularJS, `required` or `required="true"` would be enough

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the input here behaves exactly as in HTML. If you want to make an input required, just set the attribute:

```
<input type="text" required ng-model='config.test' placeholder="{{some text}}">
```

There is no need to fiddle around with the value of it.

Also, you may consider ditching `ng-model` here and instead use the [reactive-forms module](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms).